# I'm getting an error trying to find the max an min of a set of inputs by the user

Tags: python, max, minimum

This is my assigned task :

*Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and having as output:*

Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2

This is what I have so far but is not showing me the maximum neither the minimum of the inputs , as is not showing the Invalid input whenever the user try to put any word in it .

```
list = []

for i in range(2,10):
  list.append(int(input('Ingrese un número\n')))

# Ordenar lista
list.sort()

# Numero menor
print(list[0])
# Numero mayor
print(list[-1])


largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    print(num)

print("Maximum", largest)
```

Comment: Please try to structure your code correctly. It seems that you gave two solution attempts in one. And it would be helpful if you could explain what part you have a problem with.

Comment: This is a homework question and people usually don't like to answer those kind of questions, but here are few tips what you should check in your code: after your input, you should store `num` in a list. You should add `try-except` to convert input to number. User built-in `max` and `min` functions instead of sorting the list and then taking the first and the last element. PS. never call your list `list` because it shadows the built-in type...

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. You never assign anything to either *smallest* or *largest* (after initialisation to None)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
lis = []
while True:
    try:
        num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
        lis.append(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("It is not a number.. please verify!! Invalid input\n")
    check=input("If you want to continue to write number please enter. if you are done please write done:\n")
    if check.lower() == "done":
        break
print("Maximum", max(lis))
print("Minimum",min(lis))
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter a number: 7
If you want to continue to write number please enter. if you are done please write done:

Enter a number: 2
If you want to continue to write number please enter. if you are done please write done:

Enter a number: bob
It is not a number.. please verify!! Invalid input

If you want to continue to write number please enter. if you are done please write done:

Enter a number: 10
If you want to continue to write number please enter. if you are done please write done:
done
Maximum 10
Minimum 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use walrus operator (`:=`) to prompt and check if `num` equals 'done' or not. Catch invalid `num` using `try except` and add `num` to `numlist` if it can be casted to `int`. Print out the largest and the smallest `num` of `numlist` using `max()` and `min()`.

```
numlist = []
while (num := input('Enter a number: ')) != 'done':
    try: numlist += [int(num)]
    except ValueError: print('Invalid input')

print('Maximum is', max(numlist))
print('Minimum is', min(numlist))
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: bob
Invalid input
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: done
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2
```